# Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data

I saw some questions about this error but I could not find a solution for my case.

I'm implementing a paging in the spring boot application.

I Have this method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distrito",  params = { "page", "size" })
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("size") int size) throws ServletException { 
        Map<String, String>informacaoUsuario = uService.getInformacoesUsuario(request);

        Page<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarFiltro(Long.parseLong(informacaoUsuario.get("idEntidadeSelecionada")), page, size);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and my service

```
    public Page<Distritos> buscarFiltro(Long usuarioEntidade ,int size, int page){
        return distritosRepository.encontrar(usuarioEntidade, size, page);
    }
```

my repository

```
@Query( nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT dist.nome, dist.id_distrito, dist.id_entidade, dist.id_municipio, dist.id_uf, dist.codigo_dne, dist.flag_ativo,  enti.nome Entidade, muni.nome Municipio, unfe.nome UF FROM glb.distritos  dist, glb.entidades  enti, glb.municipios muni, glb.ufs unfe WHERE dist.id_entidade  = enti.id_entidade AND dist.id_municipio = muni.id_municipio AND muni.id_uf = unfe.id_uf and enti.id_entidade = :parametroId order by nome   ")
    public  Page<Distritos>  encontrar(@Param ("parametroId")Long usuarioEntidade, int size, int page);
```

and i got this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either use @Param on all parameters except Pageable and Sort typed once, or none at all!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.assertEitherAllParamAnnotatedOrNone(Parameters.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.<init>(Parameters.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

how can i solve that ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a `Pageable` Object and not the `size` and `page` like you do :

```
public  Page<Distritos>  encontrar(@Param ("parametroId") Long usuarioEntidade, 
                                                          Pageable pageable);
```

and call your method like this

```
return distritosRepository.encontrar(usuarioEntidade, new PageRequest(size, page));
```

You can either create a Pageable Object which hold a sorted attribute, so instead of using `order by nome` in your query you can use :

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Direction.ASC, "nome"));
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(size, page, sort);
return distritosRepository.encontrar(usuarioEntidade, pageable);
```

Comment: hi
Is there any benefit using "Sort " over  jpql order by ? 
thank you

Comment: Hi @soung, what did you mean by `jpql order by` even you use order by (with native query) or Sort which create your order by

Answer (score 1):

Check `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` class which is provided by Spring for pagination. Controller will extract your parameters and build it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Pageable` object instead:

```
public Page<Distritos> buscarFiltro(Long usuarioEntidade ,int size, int page){
       Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size);
       return distritosRepository.encontrar(usuarioEntidade, pageable);
}
```

and repo:

```
public  Page<Distritos>  encontrar(@Param ("parametroId")Long usuarioEntidade
         , Pageable pageable);
```